# How to lock WriteProcessMemory so that values stay constant

Tags: vb.net, memory

I've successfully implemented the WriteProcessMemory function in vb.net (WOOP!). However when I try and change a value it sometimes is automatically changed back to it's previous value. I'd like a way to lock and unlock these values if possible.

Here's the code the changes the values:

```
  _memManager.TryAttachToProcess("SomeAPP")

    Dim bytes() As Byte = _memManager.ReadBytes(xpos(0), 4)

    Dim currentx As Double = BitConverter.ToSingle(bytes, 0)

    Dim targetx As Double = currentx + 2
    bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(targetx)
    For i = 0 To xpos.GetLength(0) - 1

        _memManager.WriteBytes(xpos(i), bytes.Length, bytes)

    Next

    _memManager.DetachFromProcess()

    RichTextBox1.AppendText("compleate" & Chr(13))
```

Any help/advice or links would be great!

Comment: Are you sure performance is that worth it, really?

Comment: Sorry? What do you mean?

Comment: You could debug the target application and see, what procedure overrides your value, see where that value comes from and change that one instead, unless it resides in private memory, in which case you'll just have to brutally override the target field once it's changed (checking it every x ms and overriding it if value has changed)

Comment: Well, the above is your attempt to optimize performance, right?

Answer (score 2):

I believe what those "gamehack" - programs usually do is just changing the values on a timer. Say the memory value gets set to the new values every 100ms or so. 
 The program you are trying to target may have anti-temper mechanics in it that uses for example multiple variables for 1 value. it can't reset to the previous value if that value isn't stored somewhere else, maybe you should find this location and change the value there as well. 
I don't believe you can really permanently lock write-access to part of some other programs memory, but i may be wrong there. I guess the target would just instantly crash with a memory corruption error.